# Merge arrays without duplicates | nodejs | mongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two different models, `Users` and `Teams` where `Teams` has reference to `Users`.
I am trying to get all the teams that a user belongs and then get all the users that are members in those teams and merge them in one array without duplicates.  I have only managed to get the teams that a user belongs. Any ideas? (I'm a newbie)

My code:

```
router.get('/mention', verifyToken, async (req: any, res: any) => {

   const user = req.user as IUser;

   let allTeamsofOneUser = await Teams.find({
      user: user._id
   });
   res.send(allTeamsofOneUser);

})

export default router;
```

my code result:

```
[
    {
        "user": [
            "5f9e9ec9974ce02dc8f606e1",
            "5fa42303e2c49841b849fd21",
            "5fa2c3a50c061b558058f60f"
        ],
        "_id": "5fa533513836f503d826e6f2",
        "name": "Myteam",
        "createdAt": "2020-11-06T11:28:17.047Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-11-06T11:28:17.047Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "user": [
            "5f9e9ec9974ce02dc8f606e1",
            "5fa42303e2c49841b849fd21"
        ],
        "_id": "5faa73e583b15448d4ad93c7",
        "name": "teamteam",
        "createdAt": "2020-11-10T11:05:09.832Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-11-10T11:05:09.832Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the teams and get all the users and put them in an array, then filter the array for unique users.

```
let uniqueUsers = allTeamsofOneUser.reduce((acc, team) => {
    acc.push(...team["user"]);
    return acc;
}, []).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should scan each team, then each user in each team, and finally check that you didn't  know about him/her before.

```
let uniqueUsers = [];
allTeamsofOneUser.forEach( team => {
  team.user.forEach( user => {
    if(!uniqueUsers.some( userCandidate => user._id === userCandidate._id)) {
      uniqueUsers.push(userCandidate);
    }
  });    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution on mongoose docs:

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id },
  { $addToSet: { trackedGeckoCoins: { $each: geckoCoinIds } } },
  { new: true, projection: 'trackedGeckoCoins' }
)
  .then((doc) => res.status(200).json(doc))
  .catch(sendStatus500)
```

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/each/